# What is the purpose of calling text.flatMap(URL.init)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsurl

What is the purpose of calling text.flatMap(URL.init) in the following:

```
guard let url = someUITextField.text.flatMap(URL.init) else {
 return true
}
```

someUITextField.text is assumed to have a URL string that a user entered.

Comment: I've never seen that, I would have wrote it: `guard let urlString = someUITextField.text, let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }`, but the `flatMap` is guess avoid one unwrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` is an optional and `URL(init)` returns also an optional. The result is a double optional `URL??`

`flatMap` first transforms the `String?` to `URL??` then it removes one `?` to be able to `if let` the expression.

Please read [What’s the difference between map(), flatMap() and compactMap()?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/205/whats-the-difference-between-map-flatmap-and-compactmap) on hackingwithswift for details.

Comment: I've read that article previously.  I was not realizing the URL??.  To me I don't see a benefit over guard let urlString = someUITextField.text, let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }.  The latter being much more common and understood as well as more intuitive.  Is there any benefit?

Comment: It’s an unusual but logical syntax to ***map*** the string to URL and to ***flat***ten the optional-optional.